# How to display the content containing special character in PDF creation using Mpdf class

Tags: php

1.Content is not displaying in pdf

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/x-download");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
$pdf =  new mPDF();
$content="'gAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaA";
$pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
$pdf->Output($filename, 'D');

/*content is not displaying in PDF file, But it is displaying in web page when echo the content  */
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you haven't set the correct content type header, so that the PDF will output to browser.

Change this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-download");
```

to:

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

Secondly, your code to generate the PDF looks incorrect. For example, your html content is in `$content` but when your write it on the pdf object, you're using `$strContent` etc...

Try this:

```
// Set Header
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

// Generate & Output PDF
$pdf = new mPDF();
$content="'gAAAAgABwESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaA";
$pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Also data contains different language data like spanish,japanees